# Is there a standard/slick way to create arbitrary new remote git repos (not branches)?

Tags: git, repository

I'd love to be able to clone a project from github, make some changes, then push it to my private git server, all with a few commands. (yes, I like to share things on github too, but sometimes it needs to be private :) )

So:

1. is there a standard git-core client-supported way of doing this?
2. if not, are there any popular recipes/scripts out there I should check out?

**update**

I tried this with my setup:

```
➔ git push foo@example.com:git-test.git
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add <name> <location>
git push <name>
```

Your update shows a problem with gitosis, which is unrelated to your original question. But I will recommend not using gitosis and use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) instead.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the remote repo has to exist before doing that -- it will hook up a local repo to a remote repo but it won't create the remote repo.

Comment: Yeah it must exist before you do the `git push` but I do not believe it needs to exist for the `git remote add`. Although I believe some systems like gitolite might be able to create the repo for you.

Comment: Of course, if you're already using gitosis and are happy with it there's no compelling reason to switch to gitolite.

Comment: @John, @ebneter: Gitolite supports "wildcard repos": you specify a set of repository names (via wildcards), along with some permissions, and the users with "create" permissions can create a new repository with a name in that set simply by pushing it. Sounds like a potential reason to switch!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the repository in your gitosis config file, and create an empty, bare repo on the gitosis server for this to work. Specifically, on your gitosis server in the directory where you keep your repositories,

```
git init --bare git-test.git
```

and then

```
git push --all
```